# What is the probability of when $p=5$

Tags: probability

Now we pick a  randomly selecting  $100$  natural numbers:$a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{100}$,and such 
(1)$$a_{i}\equiv 1(mod p),a_{j}\equiv 3(mod p),A_{i}=\{i|1\le i\le 100\},A_{j}=\{j\in 1\le j\le 100\}$$
(2)$$,card(A_{i})=card(A_{j})=50,$$
(3)
$$A_{i}\cap  A_{j}= \emptyset$$
where p is prime numbers,and $p\neq 2$

question:What is the probability of when $p=5$

Comment: Please clarify your questions. It is unclear what you are asking for, anyhow the conditions related to each other. You stated that $A_i = \{ i | 1 \leq i \leq 100 \} $, which is the set of 100 positive integers, but then say that it has cardinality of 50.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this essential part of the problem is: we have a collection of balls, each having one of $p$ colors $0,1,\ldots,p-1$, where $p \geq 4$, and an infinite supply of each color.  We pick $100$ at random, and want to know what is the probability of $50$ being colored $1$ and $50$ being colored $3$.

There are $\binom{100}{50}$ sequences of length $100$ containing exactly $50$ balls that are colored $1$ and $50$ balls that are colored $3$.  There are $p^{100}$ sequences in total.

Hence the probability is $$\frac{\binom{100}{50}}{p^{100}}$$ which when $p=5$ is $$\frac{100891344545564193334812497256}{7888609052210118054117285652827862296732064351090230047702789306640625}$$ or approximately $10^{-41}$.

Comment: (I don't understand the question ... ) What is your interpretation of $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$?

Comment: I'm guessing they're typos (they must be, since the question is otherwise inconsistent): so, 100 random natural numbers split two disjoint sets of size 50: one for 1 mod p and the other for 3 mod p.  Since the probability of choosing two identical natural numbers randomly is 0, it turns into the colored ball situation.

Comment: yea, i already commented that there were parts of the question that seem contradictory to me, like the $A_i = \{i\}$ parts.